# Check if a file exists in a given directory, NOT subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I have written a shell-script that basically looks for rar files and unrars them.

To avoid unraring the same file multiple times I added a check for the type of files I'll be unraring, namely *.avi, *.mkv and *.mp4.

```
find "/mnt/media1/TV Shows/" -type f -name "*.rar" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    DIR=$(dirname "${file}")
    MKV=$(find "${DIR}" -name "*.mkv" -print0)
    AVI=$(find "${DIR}" -name "*.avi" -print0)
    MP4=$(find "${DIR}" -name "*.mp4" -print0)
    if [ ! -f "$MKV" ] && [ ! -f "$AVI" ] && [ ! -f "$MP4" ]; then
            printf "UNRARING ${DIR}\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
            sudo unrar e "${file}"
            MKV=$(find "${DIR}" -name "*.mkv" -print0)
            AVI=$(find "${DIR}" -name "*.avi" -print0)
            MP4=$(find "${DIR}" -name "*.mp4" -print0)
            if [ ! -f "$MKV" ] && [ ! -f "$AVI" ] && [ ! -f "$MP4" ]; then
                    printf "UNRAR FAILED\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
            else
                    printf "UNRAR SUCCESSFUL\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
            fi
    else
            printf "${DIR}: Found an mkv, avi or mp4 file, skipping\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
    fi
done
```

Now, the problem is that most, if not all, directories have a "Sample" subdirectory with a video file in it. This file gets flagged with my current implementation, which is not what I desire.

**I want it to look in the exact directory, `$DIR`, not any of its subdirectories.**

Currently I have made a workaround where I simply delete the Sample directory if it exists, but this breaks torrents.

I have tried experimenting a bit with -wholename but I haven't found anything that works.

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Johan

Comment: Check the manpage for 'find' on your system - mine says: "-maxdepth levels | Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of  directories below the command line arguments.  -maxdepth 0 means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-maxdepth` option to limit the find to the current directory.

```
MKV=$(find "${DIR}" -name "*.mkv" -print0 -maxdepth 0)
AVI=$(find "${DIR}" -name "*.avi" -print0 -maxdepth 0)
MP4=$(find "${DIR}" -name "*.mp4" -print0 -maxdepth 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

charlton_austin 's answer held the answer. However it was -maxdepth 1.

Complete script:

```
find "/mnt/media1/TV Shows/" -type f -name "*.rar" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    DIR=$(dirname "${file}")
    cd "${DIR}"
    MKV=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.mkv" -print0)
    AVI=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.avi" -print0)
    MP4=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.mp4" -print0)
    if [ ! -f "$MKV" ] && [ ! -f "$AVI" ] && [ ! -f "$MP4" ]; then
            printf "UNRARING ${DIR}\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
            sudo unrar e "${file}"
            MKV=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.mkv" -print0)
            AVI=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.avi" -print0)
            MP4=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.mp4" -print0)
            if [ ! -f "$MKV" ] && [ ! -f "$AVI" ] && [ ! -f "$MP4" ]; then
                    printf "UNRAR FAILED\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
            else
                    printf "UNRAR SUCCESSFUL\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
            fi
    else
            printf "${DIR}: Found an mkv, avi or mp4 file, skipping\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advances of globbing:

```
if [[ "$(ls ./*.{mkv,avi,mp4} 2> /dev/null)" != "" ]]; then
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` isn't necessary here, since you are only looking for files with a given extension in the specified directory. Just fill an array using the pattern. It doesn't appear that you need to keep files of different types separate; you are just checking that *something* got unarchived.

```
cd "$DIR"
files=( "$DIR"/*.mkv "$DIR"/*.avi "$DIR"/*.mp4 )
if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
    printf "UNRARING $DIR\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
    sudo unrar e "$file"
    files=( "$DIR"/*.mkv "$DIR"/*.avi "$DIR"/*.mp4 )
    if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
        printf "UNRAR FAILED\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
    else
        printf "UNRAR SUCCESSFUL\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
    fi
else
    printf "$DIR: Found an mov, avi, or mp4 file, skipping\n" >> /home/johan/unrarer.log
fi
```

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you don't need to use `find` to find the rar files either:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in "/mnt/media1/TV Shows/"**/*.rar; do
    ...
done
```